# Criar um get/set para a string cpf, que verifique que possui 11 digitos, sendo eles números?

Tags: c#

```
    private static string cpf;

    public bool CPF = cpf.Length == 11 && cpf.All(char.IsDigit);

    public string Cpf
    {
        get 
        { 
            return cpf;  
        }

        set 
        {
            if(CPF)
                cpf = value;
        }
    }
```

Quando eu tento criar a propriedade com os operadores **{ get; set; }** dessa forma ocorre esse erro:

"An unhandled exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in Estacionamento.exe
Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object."

Answer (score 2):

Acho que a melhor opção para você é usar uma expressão regular pois você consegue ter um controle melhor do que está validando.

E o erro que você esta tendo é porque está fazendo a validação fora do setter.

```
Regex regex = Regex("[0-9]{3}\.?[0-9]{3}\.?[0-9]{3}\-?[0-9]{2}");

private static string cpf;

public string Cpf
{
    get { return cpf;  }
    set {
        if(regex.IsMatch(value))
        {
            cpf = value;
        }
    }
}
```